Drag and drop simulation implemented in angular cdk
I am currently working on simulating drag-and-drop operations programmatically within my web application. My goal is to accurately replicate a user's drag-and-drop behavior by dispatching the appropriate events, such as mousedown, mousemove, mouseup, or pointerdown, pointermove, and pointerup.
Specifically, I am looking for guidance on:
Capturing Drag-and-Drop Events: What is the best approach to capture the necessary events and properties during a user's drag-and-drop action? How can I ensure that the captured events contain all the required data to accurately simulate the action?
Simulating Drag-and-Drop Operations: Once the events are captured, how can I programmatically dispatch them to simulate the drag-and-drop operation? Is there a way to trigger the internal application logic for drag-and-drop as if it were performed manually by the user?
Integration with Angular CDK (if applicable): I am using Angular CDK's drag-and-drop module. How can I programmatically dispatch events that will trigger Angular CDK's drag-and-drop mechanisms, including the drop function, to move elements within the application?
Event Dispatching Issues: I have attempted to dispatch pointer events to simulate the drag-and-drop action, but the expected behavior is not occurring. Could you provide insights on potential pitfalls or missed considerations that might be affecting the success of the simulation?
let pointerMoveEventProps = [];
let pointerUpEventProps = null;

document.addEventListener('pointerdown', (e) => {
    pointerDownEventProps = captureEventProps(e);
    console.log('pointerdown_element', e.target, e);

    let isDragging = false;
    const dragStartX = e.clientX;
    const dragStartY = e.clientY;

    const handlePointerMove = (e) => {
        const deltaX = e.clientX - dragStartX;
        const deltaY = e.clientY - dragStartY;

        if (Math.abs(deltaX) > 5 || Math.abs(deltaY) > 5) {
            isDragging = true;
            console.log('Element is being dragged', e);
            pointerMoveEventProps.push(captureEventProps(e));
        }
    };

    const handlePointerUp = (e) => {
        pointerUpEventProps = captureEventProps(e);
        console.log('pointerup', e.target, e);

        document.removeEventListener('pointermove', handlePointerMove);
        document.removeEventListener('pointerup', handlePointerUp);

        storeEventProps();
    };

    document.addEventListener('pointermove', handlePointerMove);
    document.addEventListener('pointerup', handlePointerUp);
});

function captureEventProps(e) {
    return {
        clientX: e.clientX,
        clientY: e.clientY,
        bubbles: e.bubbles,
        cancelable: e.cancelable,
        pressure: e.pressure,
        isPrimary: e.isPrimary,
        pointerId: e.pointerId,
        pointerType: e.pointerType,
        composed: e.composed,
        pageX: e.pageX,
        pageY: e.pageY,
        screenX: e.screenX,
        screenY: e.screenY,
        movementX: e.movementX,
        movementY: e.movementY,
        which: e.which,
        button: e.button,
        buttons: e.buttons,
        detail: e.detail
    };
}

function storeEventProps() {
    localStorage.setItem('pointerDownEventProps', JSON.stringify(pointerDownEventProps));
    localStorage.setItem('pointerMoveEventProps', JSON.stringify(pointerMoveEventProps));
    localStorage.setItem('pointerUpEventProps', JSON.stringify(pointerUpEventProps));
}

function simulateDragAndDrop(targetElement, dropTarget) {
    const pointerDownEventProps = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pointerDownEventProps'));
    const pointerMoveEventProps = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pointerMoveEventProps'));
    const pointerUpEventProps = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pointerUpEventProps'));

    if (!pointerDownEventProps || !pointerMoveEventProps || !pointerUpEventProps) {
        console.log('No event properties available for simulation');
        return;
    }

    const pointerDownEvent = new PointerEvent('pointerdown', { ...pointerDownEventProps, view: window });
    targetElement.dispatchEvent(pointerDownEvent);

    pointerMoveEventProps.forEach((position, index) => {
        console.log('INDEX', index)
        setTimeout(() => {
            const pointerMoveEvent = new PointerEvent('pointermove', {
                ...position,
                view: window,
                button: 0,
                buttons: 1
            });
            dropTarget.dispatchEvent(pointerMoveEvent);
        }, 5); // Adjusted delay
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
        const pointerUpEvent = new PointerEvent('pointerup', { ...pointerUpEventProps, view: window });
        dropTarget.dispatchEvent(pointerUpEvent);
        console.log('Drag and drop simulation completed.');
        console.log(pointerMoveEventProps.length * 5)
    }, pointerMoveEventProps.length * 5);
}

// Usage
const targetElement = document.getElementById('0');
const dropTarget = document.getElementById('cdk-drop-list-0');
simulateDragAndDrop(targetElement, dropTarget);



